# Image of a harmonic map from $S^2\to S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am asked to solve this homework

> For $f:S^2\to S^3$ a conformal and harmonic map, the range of $f$ is contained in a great $S^2$.

from a course on harmonic maps.

**My attempt:**
View $S^3\hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ so that $f$ is a $\mathbb{R}^4$-valued function.
Let $n$ be in $T_{f(p)}S^3$ the unit normal to the range of $f$, and $(x,y)$ a local isothermal coordinates of $S^2$.
Observe that $n, \partial_x f,  \partial_y f, f$ forms an orthogonal basis,
It suffices to prove $n$ is a constant vector in the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^4$.
So far I can only obtain
$$\begin{align}
\partial_x n = a(x,y)\;\partial_x f + b(x,y)\; \partial_f f\\
\partial_y n = b(x,y)\;\partial_x f - a(x,y)\;\partial_y f
\end{align}$$
for some functions $a,b$ from the definition of harmonic maps that $\Delta_{S^2}f = \lambda(x,y) f$.
By the way, this conformal structure reminds me of Liouville's theorem from complex analysis but I don't know if it helps here.

Thanks

Comment: This is quite reminiscent of Hopf’s theorem that a minimal $S^2$ in $S^3$ must be a great sphere.

Comment: @TedShifrin It seems like I cannot find that theorem via Google search. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: See Theorem 3.1 [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s13373-013-0034-2.pdf)